# Configuring RxJava to Send Data to activity from GCMListenerService

Tags: android, rx-android

I am trying to send an update to my `Activity` from my `GCMServiceListener` so, I am using `RxJava/RxAndroid` And created a `BusClass` for handling sending and `Observers`

```
public class ClientBus {

//private final PublishSubject<Object> _bus = PublishSubject.create();

// If multiple threads are going to emit events to this
// then it must be made thread-safe like this instead
private final Subject<Object, Object> _bus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());

public void send(Object o) {
    _bus.onNext(o);
}

public Observable<Object> toObserverable() {
    return _bus;
}

public boolean hasObservers() {
    return _bus.hasObservers();
}
}
```

And in my `Application Class` I did this to initialize the `BusClass`

```
private ClientBus clientBus;

public ClientBus getRxBusSingleton() {
    if (clientBus == null) {
        clientBus = new ClientBus();
    }
    return clientBus;
}
```

In the activity I want to receive the message, I registered a `CompositeSubscription` and get a reference to my `ClientBus class` from the `Application Class`

`clientBus = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getRxBusSingleton();`

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initSubscriptions();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    _subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}


void initSubscriptions() {
    _subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    _subscriptions.add(clientBus.toObserverable().subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object event) {
            Log.e("New Event", "Event Received");
            if (event instanceof MyGcmListenerService.Message) {
                String msg = ((MyGcmListenerService.Message) event).getMessage();
                if (msg.equals("Update Available")) {
                    scheduleArrayList = getSchedules();
                    scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), scheduleArrayList, ScheduledUberActivity.this);
                    scheduledList.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
                    scheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (msg.equals("Refresh")) {
                    fetchTrips();
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

And from the `MyGcmListenerService class` I did this when I get a new notification

```
 private void sendRefreshNotif() {
    if (clientBus.hasObservers()) {<--It enters the if cause the Log prints. But, the activity doesn't get the message
        Log.e("Obervers", "Observers aren't null");
        clientBus.send(new Message("Refresh"));
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why isn't it working here? I use it to interact between activities and fragments. I closed my application to check if the notification comes in, It'll enter this block `if (clientBus.hasObservers()) {` but it didn't and starting the app and testing the `Observer`, it notices there's an active Observer. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: As far as timing is concerned, are you sending the message _after_ you subscribe to the event bus?

Comment: The message would always send after `Subscribing` because my `GCMListener` class is the one sending the message. And the `Activity` waiting for the information registered the `Subscription` in it `onStart`

Comment: Why you are not using greenbus or otto?

Comment: Because they do same thing RxJava does. And I've been using RxJava in multiple scenarios in my app. Why bundled my app with more libs when one can do it. And all I need do is just learn how it works @Pedram

Comment: Because it takes your valuable time to reinvent the wheel.
otto is a simple and easy to use library, and it does all the threading stuff out of the box, Also it has only ~100 methods.

You might be interested in to a working sample for what you trying to achieve:
http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

Comment: Though, I've used Otto before migrating to RxJava. And the link you posted, is what I've been using to learn RxJava @Pedram

Comment: Post some code from GCMServiceListener. I guess it's an Observable related issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you used different instances of the `ClientBus` class in `CompositeSubscription` and `MyApplication`.
Try to make a singleton from `ClientBus` class, it works fine for me.

```
public class ClientBus {

    public ClientBus(SingletonAccessor accessor) {}

    private static ClientBus instance;
    private static class SingletonAccessor{}

    public static ClientBus getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new ClientBus(new SingletonAccessor());
        return instance;
    }

    private final Subject<Object, Object> mBus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());

    public void send(Object o) {
        mBus.onNext(o);
    }

    public Observable<Object> toObserverable() {
        return mBus;
    }

    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return mBus.hasObservers();
    }
}
```